# How to group rows and columns from parameters in rdlc report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I am using rdlc report and I'm trying to populate a Matrix with data from parameters and grouping them in rows and columns , it is working partly but it doesn't group them it just shows the first data of the parameter.
This is how I'm giving data to parameters from the code behinde ;

```
List<ReportParameter> report = new List<ReportParameter>();
            List<String> field = new List<String>();
            List<String> year = new List<String>();
            List<String> Avg = new List<String>();
            List<String> Val = new List<String>();
            foreach (var item in Entetie.ReportViews.Where(item => item.Code == "100116") )
            {
                year.Add(Convert.ToString(item.Year));
                Avg.Add(Convert.ToString(item.RegionAVG));
                field.Add(item.FieldDescription);
                Val.Add(Convert.ToString(item.FarmValue));
            }
            foreach (var item in Entetie.FinalReportViews.Where(item => item.FarmCode == "100116"))
            {
                ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("Name", item.Name + " ");
                report.Add(rp);
                ReportParameter rpz = new ReportParameter("EcoSize", Convert.ToString(item.EcoSize) + " ");
                report.Add(rpz);
                ReportParameter rps = new ReportParameter("Type", item.Type + " ");
                report.Add(rps);
                ReportParameter rpq = new ReportParameter("FieldDescription");
                rpq.Values.AddRange(field.ToArray());
                report.Add(rpq);
                ReportParameter rpe = new ReportParameter("Year");
                rpe.Values.AddRange(year.ToArray());
                report.Add(rpe);
                ReportParameter rpr = new ReportParameter("RegionAVG");
                rpr.Values.AddRange(Avg.ToArray());
                report.Add(rpr);
                ReportParameter rpt = new ReportParameter("Value");
                rpt.Values.AddRange(Val.ToArray());
                report.Add(rpt);
                ReportParameter rpa = new ReportParameter("Num", Convert.ToString(item.RegNum) + " ");
                report.Add(rpa);
            }
```

I created a list for the parameters that need to be grouped and convert that list to array because the parameter accepts only arrays.

When i generate this code the table looks like this
[image]

And i want it to look like this "This is the table that i generated when i pass the data from the dataSet directly to the table"

[image]

Is it possible to group the data which is sent from parameters.

Comment: What you want is a pivot table that groups by year which is your dataset.  So you want to bind the rdlc report to your dataset.